Does the simplicity or complexity of God even matter with respect to worldviews?
Inspired by this question here, I was wondering whether or not it even matters if God is simple or complex compared to the complexity of your entire worldview.
Even if god is simple, and the doctrine of divine simplicity was correct (and there are plenty of arguments against it), you are still positing more than what naturalism posits. In other words, you are not just positing the existence of the universe, but now also god.
Doesn’t this imply that a theistic worldview is necessarily more complex than an atheistic worldview since the latter contains only the universe and the former contains the universe and god?
Note: I am not saying that it is useless to posit new entities. Clearly, we have done that in scientific history. But when we did, they also helped us understand the world better and gave an explanation for things that we could also predict and test. I don’t see how that applies to god so this seems superfluous.

Final Note: absolutely correct. The "G-idea" can give us (humans) a lot of benefits (and also millions of victims) but it does not give us any new understanding/ explanation/ predictions about the ways the world is.

While a universe without god would be simpler, it would not necessarily be correct. So the question is confusing and opinion based.

well the point was moreso that the complexity of an entire worldview seems to matter more than a particular entity of a worldview but I’ll edit the question to make that more clear @tkruse

Your dog cares about you, you care about how your neighbors act, the practicing layman cares about the authority of the cleric to speak on issues of dogma, the cleric cares about the correctness of the dogma set by whoever sets the dogma for clerics, the people who set the dogma for clerics care about the theology, and the theologians care about the metaphysics, so your dog cares about the metaphysics six steps removed...

Since divine simplicity is not an argument made to counter agnosticism, it's silly to ask whether it matters for agnosticism. So this question seems just a variation of endless questions on "is there really a god?" Divine simplicity matters to theologicians, and nobody else. But to them, it matters.

@MauroALLEGRANZA "The G-idea does not give us any new understanding/explanation about the ways the world is" - that is wrong. True, it does not give any scientific explanations about physical properties of the world, but it gives a lot of explanations about immaterial things. Quite good explanations, actually. For example the Bible explains why many people are greedy any hungry for power but are not happy with their money and wealth. Or even more general, it explains why most of us are in some way broken or unhappy and in desperate search for a way out. Which is only Jesus, by the way.

@tkruse what are talking about? Who said anything about agnosticism? It’s silly to call things silly when you’re not even reading what is being said

Remember that this particular argument is between folks who already believe, and is not intended for anyone else, so the fact that it's meaningless unless you grant its presumptions is irrelevant. The issue was that, in a religion which has adopted the concept of hell for people who believe wrongly, there was considered to be huge danger in getting any least detail wrong, not just to yourself but to your students. Hence the attempts to nail down everything that could possibly be deduced, whether it makes any difference in this world or not, since it might gate admission to the next.

@keshlam, "Remember that this particular argument is between folks who already believe..." I beg to differ. I'm certainly not aware of any theological debates over anything so mundane to a theist as "complexity".  If you believe this is a hot topic amongst believers please provide a source for that claim. It seems to me that most of these arguments are started by atheists seeking to bolster their disbelief via some logical "catch".

@returntrue I won't argue, but your entire comment is just an opinion. Science can--and does--do those things as well!

Closed as "opinion based"  WTFudfge!!  EVERY philosophy question relies on an epistemic theory, and the appropriate epistemology is always a judgment call.  Opinion.  This question asks about the utility of a common epistemic framing -- if we can't post answers to that, we might as well shut down this board!

The doctrine of divine simplicity (DDS) is definitely not required for a consistent theistic view - it may actually be a detriment (see Plantinga's critiques of DDS's coherence).

That aside, you raise the broader idea of the complexity/simplicity of a worldview. I think the principle of parsimony is one of the most misused and misunderstood principles of theory building. One issue is the ambiguity in how we measure simplicity:

fewer entities, OR
fewer postulates/committments/natural kinds or types

?
(1) seems clearly wrong by counterexample - is matter discrete (atomistic) or continuous? Well, if there are atoms, you are requiring me to believe in the existence of countless entities that I cannot see or measure whereas if matter is continuous then each object is just one blob. One is less than countless: QED.  Yet atoms have been shown to be the correct view upon further experimentation. So we don't want to close off avenues due to the sheet number of things it posits - nature can be very complicated indeed.
(2) Seems more promising. If one worldview can explain things (we'll get to what "explain" even means later) with fewer commitments whereas another requires more commitments to get to the same place (and we cannot experimentally adjudicate between them) then why would you willing make more commitments (each commitment in a way give you more ways of being wrong)?
So, let's forget about (1) and focus on  (2) which is what I think most of us refer to when we say  "simpler".
If we assume that Theism and Naturalism are both equally explanatory, then indeed Theism has an issue: it requires a commitment to an entirely new type of entity called "God". The Naturalist can point to the universe and say "I am committed to this existing" whereas the Theist must say, "I'll take your universe and raise you a God."
If it were that simple, we'd all be Naturalists. But the problem comes down to what we mean by "both equally explanatory". What does well-explained mean?
Drawing from Aquinas, an explanation should be causal: "Effect A because of phenomena X and conditions C" (to grossly simplify). We need to be able to draw a clear line from purported causes to the observed effects.
Using this standard, Naturalistic/scientific explanations win in spades across several dimensions:

Coherence: The different levels of an explanation compose nicely, and where they don't scientists call it out for further study (e.g., GR vs QM) (admit gaps but also know how to know a solution once they see it). This ensures our knowledge is not fragmented

Transparency: There are no "magic steps" in a naturalistic explanation. Even in quantum mechanics, we can explain why we found more electrons here vs there by appeal to the wave function - its not deterministic, but we have a precise instrument at the statistical level. This ensures our "knowledge" is truly "insight".

Verifiability: Naturalistic explanations are testable (in principle...cosmology really pushes the boundaries here ;). This ensures our knowledge is reliable.

Simplicity: Naturalistic explanations achieve the above three items with as few "types" or "kinds" as possible. This ensures we do not assume more than we are warranted by the thing being explained.


Contrast this with Theistic explanations. Right off the bat, we are forced to postulate an inscrutable entity, losing transparency ("God's ways are not our ways"). We also are forced to divide causation into at least two types: natural causation and supernatural causation (miracles) so we lose coherence. We cannot test God (even in principle) so cannot verify he exists in a reliable way (lose verifiability). Finally, we have to add a commitment to our set of asserted things, so our imaginations overreach our empirical grasp.
Of course, there's a whole other dimension to Theism that Naturalism lacks in terms of social and emotional benefits and intuitiveness. But none of that really is relevant to truth.
Example: God vs Multiverse


Theist: The universe is finely tuned for life. If a God existed and wanted life to happen, it makes sense we'd see these parameters. If the universe were indifferent, then why these parameter values -- we shouldn't be here.


Naturalist: I get where you're coming from, but positing God simply pushes the question to why were we lucky enough to be in a reality that contains such a God (or any God for that matter)? I could simply say that the initial state of the universe was necessary and leave it at that - we don't know why, but it was. Postulating another mysterious thing behind an already mysterious thing doesn't solve our issue.


Theist: I don't buy that. I am only requiring a commitment to one thing: A loving, personal God. From that I get everything else. You are committed to a whole slew of brute necessities. I think I win here.


Naturalist: Hold on there! I think there's a big difference in what we are committed to. The Standard Model has these parameters, which we know exist as numbers in a theory. We also  know the universe exists. We don't know if there was any freedom to those numbers. God is simply replacing naturalistic mysterianism with divine mysterianism -- it's a solution to a potential non-problem. Let's first determine if there is a problem.


Theist: I think you're being willingly dense to the current scientific theories. Our most advanced theories (e.g., string theory, GR, QFD etc) support vast landscapes of possible universes, which is why we know how special our particular one appears to be. You need to account for how those other possibilities are ruled out a priori (and not just anthropically).


Naturalist: A lazy answer to your challenge is to say those theories are not complete and so all these free parameters represent epistemological gaps not possible ontologies. For example, I can describe oil/water/gas mixtures using empirically derived correlations/formulas that are very complex (lots of parameters) but in reality it is the result of the interaction of a few laws of fluid mechanics that dictate what all those parameters must be.
But let's say that is not the case, or we do find that these options are possibilities. In that case, I can take the view that since nothing is forbidding these options then they do in fact exist as distinct worlds. From that viewpoint, our existence in a world so finely tuned for life is no more surprising than finding out Earth and our solar system are so finely tuned for us.


Theist: Wait, so you're saying instead of accepting one additional thing (God) you want me to accept an infinite number of things (other worlds), all to explain the same thing?! You can't be serious. Your theory is way more complicated than mine.


Naturalist: You're thinking about simplicity incorrectly. Here's why: What do we actually know about reality? One thing we don't know is that there is only one world/reality. But we do know that there is at least one. Just like I don't know there are other minds out there, but I do know there is at least one. Therefore, we've established that the kind "world/universe" does exist and I am merely saying that there are more instances of this kind.
Also, I am not merely positing a multiverse to solve this one problem, but because it would also explain a slew of other mysterious things (e.g., quantum entanglement, the existence of objective probability) and is also supported by rigorous (albeit untested(able)) theory (e.g., eternal inflation, multiple worlds quantum mechanics). The theories may be wrong, but they don't leave gaps (Transparency). There are also many philosophical merits to this view (see Lewis's "On the Plurality of Worlds").
In contrast, you are positing a new kind of entity, one we cannot observe/detect, solely for the purpose of giving an emotionally tidy answer to this problem, but how does this committment transparently explain the entire gestalt of conundrums we face?

I'll leave it here but obviously the theist would have plenty of rebuttals (you can have you fill on YouTube :).

I think the strongest rebuttal I can think of is extending the same intuition one uses to reject metaphysical solipsism and accept the existence of an external world to also accept the existence of a God. Why do we accept the existence of an external world? Because of (1) direct repeated experience and (2) a strong intuition that what we are experiencing is real. So it's not inconceivable that (1) and (2) might also hold in cases in which people manage to establish a direct relationship with God. But the percentage of people who actually manage to achieve that is likely minuscule.

@user80226 I buy that :)  a direct experience would be a powerful but also intensely private fact

@Annika +1. I read the first part of your answer and consider it an excellent presentation and introduction. If I had posted the original question I would at once accept your answer. - Your dialogue in the second part I will read later.

Upvote for the creative and engaging 2 way dialog!  I guess it had to end at some point, but the only thing I don't like is that the fictional Naturalist has the last word, with a glaringly obvious softball rebuttal hanging there in mid-air...  I had to restrain myself from editing to add one more line of dialog because...  ;)

@MichaelHall lol — yes I felt it was already getting long but feel free to give the theist the final word — I’ll approve creative edits ;-)


The theistic worldview is based on the god-concept. The latter
conceives the universe according to a personal model: The creator,
law-giver and  final judge of the universe is a personal being. One
can speak to them by praying.

In the course of history Christian theology developed a complex
bunch of abstract concepts with severe methodological handicaps, see
the answers to the previous question.
Therefore a gap opens up between the personal image of god and the
abstract theological concepts. The handicap of the theistic
worldview is the complexity of its technical terms, which open up
more questions about the theological basis than explain our
experience in the world.

The naturalistic worldview learned that anthropomorphic models fail
at phenomena beyond everyday experience. In this domain scientific
models, e.g., the great theories from the 20th century, developed an impressive explanatory
power. They dismiss any anthropomorphic approach.

Summing up: The difference between the two approaches matters.
The
theistic approch operates with a naive anthropomorphic model and a
complex and inconsistent theology. The explanatory value is small
and there is no possibility to test the results.
While the
naturalistic approach operates with highly abstract models which
successfully explain many phenomena. These models advance by
conjecture and refutation. But until today they leave open some fundamental questions about the universe.



You're view of theism is a caricature. You clearly have never bothered to read a scholarly defense of Christian theology.

@DavidGudeman I did, it's not as you say. But what is your favourite work of scholary defense?

"The explanatory value is small" – I object. No physical, but many immaterial things are explained quite well by the Bible. Yes, they are not scientifically verifiable, but this does not need to make them incorrect.

@returntrue Could you please name some examples where  "immaterial things are explained quite well by the Bible." In order to learn about the type of explanation and how to check the correctness of the explanation. Thanks.

If you think Christian theology is based on a naive anthropomorphic model, then you have no familiarity with Christian theology.

What do you mean by “highly abstract” models? You phrase this in a way where it makes it seem as if naturalism is more abstract than theism which it arguably is not.

@JoWehler 2 examples:
Near death experiences: In many NDS reports, people (also non-christians!) claim to have seen a very beautiful heaven, God, family members they have never known or were deceased, a flashback of their lives or much more. Scientific explanations are, in my opinion, insufficient.
The bible on the other hand describes all of these: how heaven and God look like (Rev 21, Ez 1:26), that we will be reunited with friends and family members in heaven (John 11,25), that people get judged for their actions (Rom 14:11+12).

Happiness and fulfillment:
The bible states and explains where happiness and fulfillment come from: From walking in God's paths, being close to Him, trusting Him and ultimately from God Himself (Ps 16:11, John 15:11).
Many search for happiness in the wrong things, e.g. by wanting to be rich (Prov 15:27, Mat 6:19-20). Instead the bible explains that we should have mercy on others and give to the poor to be happy (Prov 22:9, Ps 41:1). [1/2]

Further it reveals our pride and ignorance (Ps 10:4), states where it comes from (Gen 3:1) and goes further to say that we should not trust in ourselves but in God. Those that trust in theirselves and their own knowledge are, in the end, fools (Prov 28:26, 1. Cor 3:18-20). [2/2]

It is often that the complexities of the universe can be summarised in a simple set of rules, which we call laws of physics. But this program has limitations, as there is still an insane amount of complexity in physics, and on top of that, there are arbitrary parameters that go into physics, such as the initial conditions.
But the take-away is that the information in the universe can be condensed, that the universe is not simply an independent bunch of information. On a more recent note, many physicists believe that the total information in a region is actually only as large as what can be stored on the boundary of the region (the Holographic principle).
Applying these ideas to God, the speculation would be that the existence of God is not added complexity that is independent of the universe, but is instead something that explains the rest of the universe in a simple way and effectively condenses our understanding of the universe (more than our current understanding of physics does). Of course, this is just a speculation and there is no evidence for this. Also, this is just my interpretation of your questions. I can't be sure that this is the standard answer.

"Out of intense complexities, intense simplicities emerge." -- Winston Churchill

You ask (emphasis by me):

Doesn’t this imply that a theistic worldview is necessarily more complex than an atheistic worldview since the latter contains only the universe and the former contains the universe and god?

It is not logically necessary that one universe and God are more complicated than another universe and God. My emphasis may indicate my point: A universe in which a God exists may be very much simpler than one where everything must be explained without God, which therefore is terribly complicated. Therefore, the sum of a universe plus God may be less complex than a — very different! — universe that needs to carry with it all provisions to be "on its own".
Without being too derisive: Apart from the quite unbearable infinity of the universe, opposed by our equally unbearable finiteness, and our unbearable, lonely Geworfenheit — apart from that, our unbearable and fundamental ignorance may indeed be one motivation to believe in a God who explains everything very nicely, if in doubt by recurring to the unfathomability of His ways.

Counter-argument: My son argued, probably correctly, that a system that exposes a certain behavior (in this case, the universe we observe, be it with or without God) will need a certain minimal complexity in order to produce this behavior. Whether we partition the system in two (universe + God) or leave it monolithic (stand-alone universe) does not change this fundamental fact. But the "rump universe" of the (universe + God) case may well be much simpler than the "stand-alone" universe because large parts of the complexity can be sequestered into God.

To complement the first part of your answer: the motion of Mars in the Earth's sky has a less complicated explanation of we include the Sun in our system.

Positing the existence of a God, regardless of its complexity, might matter if it could explain things that naturalism can't explain equally well, at least intuitively. For example, the reason why most people reject metaphysical solipsism and posit an external world, the passage of time, the reliability of their memory, the existence of other minds, etc., is because the intuition that those things are real seems experientially and intuitively irresistible. Likewise, it seems conceivable that perhaps God might be able to reach a similar epistemic status for certain people who claim to be able to "experience" or have a "relationship" with God (provided God actually exists and can produce that epistemic effect on them). A skeptic might object to this by arguing that all experiences of God are mere illusions, but by the same reasoning, one could also claim that all experiences of an external world are also an illusion, and we are back to solipsism.
And by the way, a reminder: if we are going to use Occam's Razor to define our worldviews, keep in mind that it might favor metaphysical solipsism: Does Occam's Razor favor metaphysical solipsism?

I suppose it would depend on what you consider an explanation. Even if a person claims to experience god, there is presumably no explanation for how god causes that particular experience or why that particular experience occurs instead of another. Even many believers point out that god works in mysterious ways. But if he works in mysterious ways, you don’t have an explanation, and thus there’s no explanatory benefit in positing him. You can’t have it both ways I think

@Syed You face the same problem with physicalism and the hard problem of consciousness, reconciling quantum mechanics and relativity, finding a replacement for String Theory (video), etc.

what you’re saying is that there are unsolved problems in physicalism, but how are any of those problems solved with god? It’s not about whether physicalism explains everything. It’s about whether there’s an explanatory advantage in positing god @user80226

@Syed Is there an explanatory advantage in positing your mother even if you can't explain with 100% details how your mother works? Does it make sense for a 5-year old child to posit the existence of their parents if they lack the knowledge to explain how their parents work? Should 5-year olds be solipsists, since they can't explain the reality that surrounds them?

that is akin to asking whether someone in the Bronze Age should posit the non existence of germs. Sure, a lack of knowledge may make it more or less reasonable to believe in certain things, but we do have knowledge, and so postulating hypotheticals where we don’t have this knowledge is fruitless @user80226

@Syed So, likewise, what would be the problem with someone gaining progressively more knowledge of God?

none, but there seems to be no one who has explained how god works so far! @user80226

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Syed Reply available in chat above.

If we are people, then there is no reason to think we are the only person. So I guess if we were gods, there would be no reason to think we were the only god? But we as people don't have experience of gods, so transitivity doesn't seem to apply. And if it did, why stop at one? Why not universes and universes of gods and gods?

@Syed further reply posted in chat.

Physicalism is for dummies (Ulianov Lenin). And the more we learn about this world, the less confidence we have about explaining fundamental questions about our reality. Laws of physics could be a visible part of this video game. But can you explain where they are coming from? Why they are created in a coherent and consistent way. And what was the purpose of their creation?
